# Дополнительная панель с кнопками при редактировании таблицы, как в сообщениях на iOS

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Я перерыл весь интернет, но так и не нашел ответа; в сообщениях при редактировании списка вылезает дополнительная панель с кнопками, см. картинку.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Не могу понять, это родной функционал UITableView? (скорее всего нет)
Или же это отдельный view, который приезжает поверх таблицы?
Подскажите, в правильную сторону хоть копаю. На Swift все делаю.

Comment: Это очень сильно похоже на отдельную вьюху, которая выезжает поверх таблицы. И реализация там не оч сложная на самом деле.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуй использовать `UIToolbar`

```
let toolbar = UIToolbar(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: 50))
        toolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyle.default
        toolbar.items = [
            UIBarButtonItem(title: "Отмена", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.plain, target: self, action: #selector(cancelAction)),
            UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.flexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil),
            UIBarButtonItem(title: "Далее", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.plain, target: self, action: #selector(nextAction))]
        toolbar.sizeToFit()
```

Для показа

```
view.addSubview(toolbar)
```

Для скрытия

```
toolbar.removeFromSuperView
```

Comment: Все верно, так и сделал, не успел сам отписаться. Только я бы добавил строки как показать его и убрать, потому что `inputAccessoryView` у таблицы не задать, а в документации к `UIToolbar` сказано только об этом варианте, новичку о других тяжело догадаться